# How to reduce computation when making combination of feature vectors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have two classes of feature vectors, lets call them A and B (each of dimension d). Now I can take one vector from class A and one vector from class B, perform a linear operation on them to get a resultant vector also of dimension d. *(Note: The linear operation is not important here, you can assume it to be simple vector addition).*

Lets call the class of resultant vector as C. Clearly computing resultant class C, is O(n^2) task.

Now, I need to find similarity between a query vector (q) and a subset of vectors in class C *(The subset is formed based on a criterion on the vectors in class C).* If a vector 'x' in this subset is similar to the vector 'q' above a threshold, the output will be original vectors from classes A and B, whose combination made the vector 'x'.

What is the fastest way to do this if I am ready to compromise a little on accuracy of both, finding the subset of class C based on the criterion as well as, of finding the similarity of query vector.

I have thought of precomputing the class C, but even thousand feature vectors in each class will result in a million combination. I think some clustering might help but I am unable to reach a concrete solution.

Comment: How many vectors are in A and B each?

Comment: can be a lot more than 1000.

Comment: What can be a valid solution depends on the actual numbers a bit. You could separate the vector space into regions, their size depending on the threshold, and cache the vector combinations that result in vectors from C to be within each region. But if the threshold is very small and the distribution of C within the vector space vary sparse, that won"t work.

Comment: Have a look at k-nearest-neighbor from scikit learn, if you haven't already. You might be able to have a couple of quick runs with it to test whether that works: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html